# Joomla K2 component and image resize - how to disable

Tags: image, resize, joomla2.5, space, k2

I am using K2 component, but as you now it creates different sizes of an image. How can I disable this. I want to create only the sizes I am using  - I know which sizes I am using - it's M and L size, but all the others I am not using and they are using a lot of server space

So can you help me to solve this even if it must be hard coded

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you create module there it will ask for image size specify size over there in which size you need to show the image

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I don't want K2 to create all image sizes, and this is because I don't want to lose disk space. That's why I want to disable the creation of all image sizes

Comment: OK Is there a way to make k2 to not creating all size of images, but only these which I am using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra fields for that. Dont add any image in k2 but add M and L image to k2 extra fields. Of course you have to xreate the fields first